# WPF MetroTheme = Icon Ressources

Tags: c#, wpf, colors, icons, mahapps.metro

Icon on button with Icon ressources Metro

I want to add image in my button with the metro pack icon, but i cant add the resources in my App.xaml

I used this command :  `Install-Package MahApps.Metro.Resources`
and added `<ResourceDictionary Source="/Resources/Icons.xaml" />`
In my App.xaml but this line didnt work, I have an error...

So I cant add my image with `<VisualBrush Visual="{StaticResource appbar_add}" />`

Source: [official documentation](https://mahapps.com/docs/styles/buttons)
But I cant use the icon resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MahApps.Metro.Resources package does not contain the styles for those circle buttons. Use command `Install-Package MahApps.Metro`.

App.xaml:
[image: App.xaml]

MainWindow.xaml:
[image: Window.xaml]

Result:
[image: Result]

Comment: This is my problem... my wierd problem ! http://puu.sh/bMg52/d7b54cf03b.png

Hum I see. This Resource are added in my folder but not in my solution. 

SO, SOLVED. Thx

Comment: I was missing the Resource Dictionary in the `App.xaml` if any other beginners aren't able to get the icons working.

Answer (score 1):

The Fill property on each path in Icons.xaml references a nonexistent BlackBrush:

[image: BlackBrush issue]

You can fix this by replacing "{DynamicResource BlackBrush}" with "Black" or including [Colors.xaml](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/master/MahApps.Metro/Styles/Colors.xaml) in your App.xaml.

[image: Fixed]

Comment: I see but its for icon pack, not the color. How can I get the icon pack Metro ?

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't understand your question, please add more detail.

Comment: I want to make this : http://puu.sh/bLdyX/b3692f135c.png

http://mahapps.com/controls/buttons.html

But I cant use the icon ressource

Answer (score 0):

I'm using that package too in my WPF apps (**MahApps.Metro**), but I can only reference icons using DynamicResource (so, *not using StaticResource*), for example:

```
<VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{DynamicResource appbar_magnify}" />
```

Look at the [official documentation here](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro.Resources#usage)